# Google Maps API v3 - detecting state of street names toggle on satallite map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to detect the state of the "Labels" toggle (i.e. show street names) in a V3 satellite map? I searched the API docs up and down but couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation for MapTypeId](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId) MapTypeId.SATELLITE is the satellite imagery with no lables.  MapTypeId.HYBRID has the labels.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes

To retrieve the current MapTypeId use [google.maps.Map.getMapTypeId](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)